# When I compute the average from a set of data in a file can I skip the first line

Tags: text-processing, awk

When I execute the following command:

```
awk '{T=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) T+=$i; T/=NF; printf "%12.7f\n",T}'
```

is there any way I can skip the first line? Maybe something like `NR!=1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, something like `NR!=1`, or `NR > 1`:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {T=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) T+=$i; T/=NF; printf "%12.7f\n",T}'
```

If you want to do this over multiple files, use `FNR` instead:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 {T=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) T+=$i; T/=NF; printf "%12.7f\n",T}'
```

(I find the inequality clearer: to me it indicates explicitly that we’re interested in records *after* a specific record.)

Answer (score 0):

you can also optimize your command as following and also error-handling on *`division by zero`* error in case of empty lines or line containing non-numeric fields and also to validate values of a column if it's really a *number* to avoid counting and dividing on *`NF`* variable instead as it will gives you wrong result, do as following:

Tested input-file:

```
6 c v g
         <-- empty line
d b d s
         <-- mixed of Tabs/Spaces
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

The command:

```
awk '
{
    T=nf=0;
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        nf+=($i+0==$i?1:0);
        T+=$i;
    };
    printf ("%12.7f\n", T/(nf?nf:1) );
}' infile
```

Output:

```
   6.0000000
   0.0000000
   0.0000000
   0.0000000
   2.5000000
   6.5000000
```

well, to skip the first line, yes you can do

`NR!=1`  or `NR>1` to skip first line from single/multiple inputs; or
`FNR!=1`  or `FNR>1` to skip first line from each single inputs;